# Raphael JS - Rotate whole set resulting in weird rotation

Tags: javascript, raphael

**[EDITED because I made progress]**

I have this wheel with text that spans linearly.

Here's the JS Fiddle to show the visual and my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/DarcFiddle/F3gsD/10/

So I create a set:

```
paper.setStart();
// draw draw draw
var set = paper.setFinish();
```

Then here's a method to rotate it:

```
var degree = 0;
function rotateSet() {
  degree = degree + 90;
  set.animate({ transform: ["R", degree, canvasCenter, canvasCenter]}, 500 );
}
```

You can try this by clicking the "Rotate" button from the JSFiddle.

But as you can see, the element also rotate on its own center, which break the structure.

What can I do to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're desired end effect is, but you could switch your initial element.rotate command to a element.transform('r'+angle) and I think you will find it behaves slightly different. I'm not sure if you are wanting the text to rotate or always stay static (so its never upside down though).

Comment: Hi Ian, yes I want the text to be static, so it still form the sun shape. I'll try initially rotate with transform

Comment: Hmm I suspect if you want it to be static but rotating, you may need to provide an opposite-rotation to compensate around the text center (so you have 2 transforms, one around the circle centre, and a reverse around the text centre). Another approach could be animating along a path for a variation, but depends on the end goal. Another option could be just use a translation transform using sin/cos, but not sure how easy that is. I may be wrong though, just a couple of ideas!

Comment: Hi thanks, double rotation might works, I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with double rotation

http://jsfiddle.net/DarcFiddle/F3gsD/12/

So, I loop the set and do two `r` transformation. First one is the center of the circle and second one is rotate back only the text as suggested by **Ian** in the comment above.

```
set.forEach(function(e) {
    var textDegree = Math.round( Raphael.angle(e.attr("x"), e.attr("y"), x, y) );

    if(e.attr("text-anchor") === "end") {
      textDegree = textDegree - 180;
    }

    e.animate({
      transform: ["r", degree, x, y, "r", textDegree, e.attr("x"), e.attr("y")]
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: For other reference: The first rotation has this weird shrink-expand animation. The easiest way to fix this is to do one dummy animation with 0 sec time on load.